# Jquery function won't work in header using Document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I am trying to add a preloader to my website with Bootstrap. My problem occurs when I use the default bootstrap's `JQuery` version of i.e. `3.2.1` but when I use `JQuery` versions like `1.9.1` it works like a charm but other Bootstrap function stop working I tried to fix the issue but I am totally fail so is there any way to make this function compatible with `JQuery's 3.2.1` or what I am missing in my code? You can view my [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ox6Lyda/)

Here is my simple code

```
<html>
<body>
<p>hello world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
$(window).ready(function(){
    $( "body" ).prepend( '<div id="preloader"><div id="status">Testing Loader</div></div>' );
    $(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
    $('#preloader').delay(750).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
    $('body').delay(750).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, i f don't include the `script` tags in the HTML it'll never work.

Comment: @Baruch I already have `script` tags

Comment: Oh. Could you paste your actual code instead of a sample that's not accurate?

Comment: Your sample doesn't even include bootstrap. Does it make sense to keep the window.load eventhandler inside the documentready event handler? I would think upside down makes more sense, just like you can see in the [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4ox6Lyda/1/)

Comment: @Icepickle As I said the JQuery version 3.2.1 causes the issue and gave the link to my fiddle did you test?

Comment: why don't u add both bootstrap js, and the simple jquery. so it works well

Comment: @Salman the simple function doesn't even works with the Jquery did you test that fiddle?

Comment: The jQuery event $(window).ready will come some milliseconds after onload event if the page doesn't have much to load.
This is delay is due to jQuery implementation.
Due to this reason, onLoad event is not executed as it is handled inside OnReady and OnReady is executed after OnLoad. You can test the same by putting alert box inside OnLoad event. It will never show alert box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a problem with `jQuery` version. Do not use `$(window).ready(..` like the following:

```js
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
    $( "body" ).prepend( '<div id="preloader"><div id="status">Testing Loader</div></div>' );
    $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
    $('#preloader').delay(750).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
    $('body').delay(750).css({'overflow':'visible'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>hello world</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but I need to execute the function before loading whole code

Comment: @Rtra Then add the preloader to your html and remove it when the document has loaded

Answer (score 0):

You could have your loader `div` static in you `html`, and `fadeOut()` if site is loaded. In that case you should build a fallback with `<noscript>`.

### html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <p>hello world</p>
    <div id="preloader">
      <div id="status">Testing Loader</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).on('load', function() {
    $('#status').fadeOut(300);
    $('#preloader').delay(400).fadeOut(600);
  });
});
```